# Using arrayController results in "Cannot perform operation without a managed object context"

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I am rewriting my previous objC app in Swift 2.2. This is cocoa application where I am using `NSArrayController` to fill `NSTableView` contents.
The error is obvious, although similar setup worked in Objective C app.

Here is my AppDelegate:

```
 var coreStack:AP_CoreDataStack!
var mainContext:NSManagedObjectContext!

override func awakeFromNib() {
coreStack = AP_CoreDataStack(){ (result) -> () in
        if result {
            self.mainContext = self.coreStack.mainContext
        }
    }
}
```

Setup of Core Data Stack

```
// MARK: - AP_CoreDataStack Class
class AP_CoreDataStack {

let mainContext: NSManagedObjectContext
let mastercontext: NSManagedObjectContext
var workerContext: NSManagedObjectContext?


internal typealias CallBack = (result:Bool) -> Void
init ( callback: CallBack) { 


    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("appNameSWIFT", withExtension: "momd")
    if (modelURL == nil) {
        print("Failed to initialize modelURL: \(modelURL)")
    }

    let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL!)
    if mom == nil {
        print("Failed to initialize model")
    }

    let psc = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: mom!)

    mastercontext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .PrivateQueueConcurrencyType)
    mastercontext.persistentStoreCoordinator = psc

    mainContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: .MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    mainContext.parentContext = mastercontext


    // add store to psc in background thread
    let qualityOfServiceClass = QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND
    let backgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(qualityOfServiceClass, 0)
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, {
        //BACKGROUND THREAD
        // adding store to persistent store coordinator
        let options = [NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:true,
            NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:true]
        do {
            // store = try psc.addP
            try psc.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: applicationDocumentDirectory(), options: options)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error: Failed to load store \(error.localizedDescription), \(error.userInfo)")
        }

        // MAIN THREAD
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            // On Main thread pass message that stack setup is complete
            callback(result: true)
        })
    })


}
```

Above is the Swift version of my Obj C code which worked fine. I have an `NSArrayController` in xib file which is bound to `Entity` and `NSManagedObjectContext` in IB:

```
// Bind To Delegate
self.mainContext
```

It seems Array controller is accessing mainContext before it is initialised, but this is the same setup which worked in objC, so why it is causing error in Swift.

EDIT: I am using regular xib file.

EDIT 2:

Evidently mainContext is not nil as calling it here works correctly

```
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AP_EntityA")
    let list:Array<AnyObject>
    do {
        list = try coreStack.mainContext.executeFetchRequest(request)
        for item in list {
            let product = item as! AP_EntityA
           print("item name is: \(product.uniqueName)")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // failure
        print("Fetch failed: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

}
```

Comment: When was and now is the nib / storyboard controller instantiated?

Comment: @Wain, I am using regular xib file where you get an NSWindow. It gets instantiated when app loads. I am not creating any additional view Controller objects.

Comment: Did you copy or recreate the XIB?

Comment: @Willeke, No, I didn't. Strangely `NSArrayController` is not recognising `mainContext` even after coreDataSetup completion. Programatically doing `self.arrayController.prepareContent()` result in same error. I can fetch data by executing request on the same context though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `dynamic` keyword to make Swift properties KVO compliant.

```
dynamic var mainContext:NSManagedObjectContext!
```